# How does the iso work in ccd\cmos array detectors

Tags: analog, cmos, ccd

I'm curious to know how exactly does the iso sensitivity work in ccd's or cmos detectors that DSLR cameras have? I understand this is a amplification of the raw signal that each pixel has, but is in amplified before digitizing it or after? Can this be accessed manually with a developer kit of some sort (say I want iso 75 instead of 100)? can it be assigned to spesific pixels or pixel lines?

I'd appreciate your insights.

Comment: If you have a Canon DSLR the Magic Lantern project is worth a look. I haven't had a detailed look at the source code but it may answer those questions for Canon cameras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a programmable gain amplification stage of some sort between the sensor readout electronics and the ADC.  The readout electronics are basically gigantic buffered mux (or cascade of muxes) with one input for every pixel.  Generally the gain stage beween the readout circuitry and the ADC is built with a series of switchable amplifier stages so the adjustment works in a series of discrete 'steps'.  No, you cannot select whatever gain you want, you can only select gains that the sensor readout is wired to support.  However, it is possible for a sensor to have readout electronics that support setting different gain settings in different ways.  In principle, it is possible to change the gain setting pixel by pixel.  Unfortunatley, the readout electronics are usually not designed so that the gain changes can be synchronized with the pixel outputs on a pixel by pixel basis.  However, some cameras read out more than one line at a time through separate gain stages and ADCs.  The Magic Lantern firmware for some Canon DSLRs supports configuring the readout electronics in those cameras to read out alternating rows in two different ISO settings.  See: http://www.magiclantern.fm/forum/index.php?topic=7139.0

Actually, most DSLR cameras do not support all of the ISO selections natively.  They perform some futzing around after the ADC that results in some ISO settings having a better dynamic range and noise level than others.

http://shootintheshot.joshsilfen.com/2010/05/13/canon-hd-dslr-native-iso/